# DotNetNuke with SQL Server Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, dotnetnuke-6

I am using DotNetNuke Content Management Systems.Following are the database requirements for DotNetNuke.

Database Server

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2005 or
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 or
Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express or
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express or
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 or
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express R2
```

If I planned to use SQL Server it will be more expensive. In some article I read the news they said  microsoft SQL Server Express is free one.

1. What is difference between SQL Server and SQL Server Express?.
2. `DataBase.mdf` file is enough to run the DotNetnuke website. Why I need database?

Comment: Difference: SQL Server **Express** is limited (in size: max. 4 GB resp. 10 GB in 2008 R2 and newer; can use only 1 CPU and max. 1 GB of RAM). Just having the `.mdf` doesn't help - you need the **server engine** to make **use of that file!**

Comment: Hi Marc_s Thanks for quick response... So In hosting time i need to buy the SQL Server?  otherwise for server engine  I can use SQL Express ?

Comment: In order to use your `database.mdf` file, you **must have** a SQL Server installation - Express or otherwise. As long as you can live within the limitations of SQL Server Express, you can use Express everywhere.